# how to make the relation between many to many and one to many?

Tags: laravel, database, postgresql, eloquent, relationship

Suppose we have 3 entities named `A`, `B`, and `C`. And Relations between these Entities are something like this:

```
A -- one to many --> B
B -- many to many --> C
```

Example tables:

```
A
| id |
| -- |
| 1  |
| 2  |

B
| id | a_id |
| -- | -- |
| 1  | 1 |
| 2  | 2 |

B_C
| b_id | c_id |
| -- | -- |
| 1  | 1 |
| 2  | 2 |

C
| id |
| -- |
| 1  |
| 2  |
```

If we wanna make the relationship between `A` and `C` in laravel, what should we do? is it possible at all?

Comment: I think hasManyThrough will do your job but I am not 100 percent sure. try it and also let me know

Comment: I tried before but `hasManyThrough` connects nested one-to-many relationships.

Comment: Just define them just how you define the relationship of your entites

Answer (score 0):

For these situations, you can use `Has Many Through` relationships and for more information, you can follow the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).
to get the relation between your A and C model you can use has many though like this:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class A extends Model
{
    
    public function c()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
         C::class, 
         B::class,
        'a_id', // Foreign key on the a table...
        'b_id', // Foreign key on the b table...
        'id', // Local key on the a table...
        'id' // Local key on the b table...);
    }
}
```

The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the name of the intermediate model.

Comment: `Has Many Through` is used when the relationships between A and B and between B and C are of a one-to-many type, but I have a many-to-many relationship between B and C. I updated the question please see it again.

Comment: @Nothehi please declare the Models with their attributes, not A, B, C, and D so that we can provide you with a good and perfect solution.